# How to determine that two Win32 API handles represent the same object?

Tags: c++, winapi, handle

Suppose I have two hanldes:

```
HANDLE h1;
HANDLE h2;
```

And both have received values resulted from some Windows API function - in particular, I'm interesed in handles resulted from calls to `CreateFile()`. How do I determine that `h1` and `h2` reference the same underlying object - in the case of `CreateFile()` - same file, directory or device? Is there some API to determine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GetFinalPathNameByHandle and compare the file path of both handles.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: or can use ZwQueryObject with ObjectNameInformation infoclass - this will be work and on xp too

Comment: According to MSDN, there is no such constant - ObjectNameInformation. Please check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550964(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

New for Windows 10:

CompareObjectHandles - Compares two object handles to determine if they refer to the same underlying kernel object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt438733(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The [GetFileInformationByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952.aspx) API returns information that can be used to uniquely identify the referenced object:

> You can compare the VolumeSerialNumber and FileIndex members returned in the [BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363788.aspx) structure to determine if two paths map to the same target; for example, you can compare two file paths and determine if they map to the same directory.

For example:

```
bool SameFile( HANDLE h1, HANDLE h2 ) {
    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION bhfi1 = { 0 };
    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION bhfi2 = { 0 };
    if ( ::GetFileInformationByHandle( h1, &bhfi1 ) &&
         ::GetFileInformationByHandle( h2, &bhfi2 ) ) {
        return ( ( bhfi1.nFileIndexHigh == bhfi2.nFileIndexHigh ) &&
                 ( bhfi1.nFileIndexLow  == bhfi2.nFileIndexLow ) &&
                 ( bhfi1.dwVolumeSerialNumber == bhfi2.dwVolumeSerialNumber ) );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this work for handles to devices, as mentioned in the question?

Comment: handles to devices - not exist. when you try open device, always FILE_OBJECT is created and you got handle for it. faster need ask - are this work for not filesystem devices - no not work. even not for all filesystems serial number - primary for ntfs

Comment: What about network shares & netwok drives? Say I have \\server\share mounted as drive X: and I get one file handle from opening file as \\server\share\somefile.txt and another file handle from opening X:\somefile.txt. In fact, I have opened the same file in the both cases. Is the approach with file paths works in this case, if I specify flag FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED? Is the by handle info works? And I want to compilcate situation even more. Assume \\server\share provided by Linux host running Samba. What works for this case?